# How to determine what event is disabling Sticky Keys?

Tags: ubuntu, logs, kde, keyboard, troubleshooting

I have an ongoing problem with Kubuntu 14.10, when using the computer I find that [Sticky Keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StickyKeys) is suddenly disabled. I reenable the feature, but in after some time (measured as three minutes to days) the feature is disabled again. Previous versions of Kubuntu did not have this issue, i.e. I've used Sticky Keys on Kubuntu unimpeded for years. **There is no mention of anything unusual in `dmesg`.**

I wrote this line to inform me of the exact second when Sticky Keys becomes disabled, but I have yet to find any reason:

```
date && echo 'start' && while true ; do xkbset q | md5sum | grep -v '087e8692adb9691fc4b4169471e2a077' && date && beep ; sleep 1 ; done
```

The issue might not happen for days, or it might suddenly occur every three minutes. The issue arises even if I'm not actively using the computer, i.e. I'll here it start beeping when I'm in another room.

Maddeningly, it seems that *very rarely* Sticky Keys will be reenabled after only a few seconds, then disable itself again. See here that I enabled the watcher at `13:48:35`, and Sticky Keys got disabled at `13:57:00`. Then, for some reason, from `13:57:09` Sticky Keys was reenabled before being disabled again at `13:57:21`. This whole sequence occurred while I was washing dishes in another room:

```
Mon Aug 31 13:48:35 IDT 2015
start
04974f8ab2d6f561ada83a2231e8fd80  -
Mon Aug 31 13:57:00 IDT 2015
04974f8ab2d6f561ada83a2231e8fd80  -
Mon Aug 31 13:57:01 IDT 2015
04974f8ab2d6f561ada83a2231e8fd80  -
Mon Aug 31 13:57:02 IDT 2015
04974f8ab2d6f561ada83a2231e8fd80  -
Mon Aug 31 13:57:03 IDT 2015
04974f8ab2d6f561ada83a2231e8fd80  -
Mon Aug 31 13:57:04 IDT 2015
04974f8ab2d6f561ada83a2231e8fd80  -
Mon Aug 31 13:57:06 IDT 2015
04974f8ab2d6f561ada83a2231e8fd80  -
Mon Aug 31 13:57:07 IDT 2015
04974f8ab2d6f561ada83a2231e8fd80  -
Mon Aug 31 13:57:08 IDT 2015
04974f8ab2d6f561ada83a2231e8fd80  -
Mon Aug 31 13:57:09 IDT 2015
04974f8ab2d6f561ada83a2231e8fd80  -
Mon Aug 31 13:57:21 IDT 2015
04974f8ab2d6f561ada83a2231e8fd80  -
Mon Aug 31 13:57:22 IDT 2015
04974f8ab2d6f561ada83a2231e8fd80  -
Mon Aug 31 13:57:23 IDT 2015
04974f8ab2d6f561ada83a2231e8fd80  -
Mon Aug 31 13:57:24 IDT 2015
04974f8ab2d6f561ada83a2231e8fd80  -
Mon Aug 31 13:57:25 IDT 2015
04974f8ab2d6f561ada83a2231e8fd80  -
Mon Aug 31 13:57:27 IDT 2015
04974f8ab2d6f561ada83a2231e8fd80  -
Mon Aug 31 13:57:28 IDT 2015
04974f8ab2d6f561ada83a2231e8fd80  -
Mon Aug 31 13:57:29 IDT 2015
^C
```

I have left the machine with no user processes running, i.e. no Firefox, Okular, Thunderbird, LibreOffice, etc, however the issue continues to occur.

**How might I debug this issue from a Linux perspective?** Surely there is some event that occurs to signal Sticky Keys to disable. **How might i determine what that event is?** This is the end of `dmesg`, and it does not grow when the issue occurs:

```
[437743.582168] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[437744.264830] usb 2-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 16 using ehci-pci
[437744.362557] usb 2-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=07a5
[437744.362562] usb 2-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[437744.362564] usb 2-1.4: Product: Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v9.0
[437744.362566] usb 2-1.4: Manufacturer: Microsoft
[437744.365110] input: Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v9.0 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.0/0003:045E:07A5.0022/input/input47
[437744.365284] hid-generic 0003:045E:07A5.0022: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v9.0] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4/input0
[437744.369877] input: Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v9.0 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.1/0003:045E:07A5.0023/input/input48
[437744.370016] hid-generic 0003:045E:07A5.0023: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v9.0] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4/input1
[437744.389238] input: Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v9.0 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.2/0003:045E:07A5.0024/input/input49
[437744.391328] hid-generic 0003:045E:07A5.0024: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v9.0] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4/input2
[437763.788707] audit: type=1400 audit(1441003016.010:106): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/ntpd" name="/etc/hosts_files/hosts.mvps" pid=4855 comm="ntpd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[437768.859972] audit: type=1400 audit(1441003021.087:107): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/ntpd" name="/etc/hosts_files/hosts.mvps" pid=4855 comm="ntpd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[437773.948118] audit: type=1400 audit(1441003026.173:108): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/ntpd" name="/etc/hosts_files/hosts.mvps" pid=4855 comm="ntpd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[437774.016734] audit: type=1400 audit(1441003026.241:109): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/ntpd" name="/etc/hosts_files/hosts.mvps" pid=4855 comm="ntpd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[437779.140972] audit: type=1400 audit(1441003031.366:110): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/ntpd" name="/etc/hosts_files/hosts.mvps" pid=4855 comm="ntpd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

What other logs should I be looking at? **What logging should I enable to find the culprit?** The command `xkbset q` shows the state of Sticky Keys, ideally I would find where it is getting its information from and then log whatever causes changes to that. Is this even possible?

Comment: maybe your file system is corrupt and the info about sticky bit is lost every time?

Comment: Thank you Edward. There are no other signs of a corrupt file system, and in fact the **symptom** is not that `xkbset q` shows the feature as disabled but rather that the feature really is disabled! The `kxbset` check is just to let me know the exact second that it gets disabled, which I was hoping would lead me to discovering what causes it to get disabled.

Comment: @dotancohen did you find a solution to this? It happens for me, also. Thanks

Comment: @Taw I never discovered the cause of the issue. I've since retired that computer, and though I'm using the same keyboard on another computer the issue is not recurring. So I think it was hardware-related, but not the keyboard.